# Phone calls permission

Tags: java, android

Everybody ask me why my app requires phone calls permission, and I don't know what to say, cause I did not add any phone calls permission to my manifest file. Here are my permissions:

```
<uses-permission " />
<uses-permission >
<uses-permission " />
<uses-permission >
<uses-permission " />
<uses-permission >
```

And here's what Google Play says:

```
THIS APPLICATION HAS ACCESS TO THE FOLLOWING:
NETWORK COMMUNICATION
FULL NETWORK ACCESS
Allows the app to create network sockets and use custom network protocols. The browser and other applications provide means to send data to the internet, so this permission is not required to send data to the internet.
CONNECT AND DISCONNECT FROM WI-FI
Allows the app to connect to and disconnect from Wi-Fi access points and to make changes to device configuration for Wi-Fi networks.
PHONE CALLS
READ PHONE STATUS AND IDENTITY
Allows the app to access the phone features of the device. This permission allows the app to determine the phone number and device IDs, whether a call is active and the remote number connected by a call.
Hide
NETWORK COMMUNICATION
VIEW NETWORK CONNECTIONS
Allows the app to view information about network connections such as which networks exist and are connected.
VIEW WI-FI CONNECTIONS
Allows the app to view information about Wi-Fi networking, such as whether Wi-Fi is enabled and name of connected Wi-Fi devices.
CHANGE NETWORK CONNECTIVITY
Allows the app to change the state of network connectivity.
```

What's going on here?

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney"
    android:versionCode="7"
    android:versionName="1.3.3" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/> 
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.Kviz"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.KVIZ" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.SwarmPopup"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.SWARMPOPUP" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.Pravila"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.PRAVILA" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

            <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.NetPopup"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.NETPOPUP" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.Kviz10Medium"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.KVIZ10MEDIUM" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.Kviz20Medium"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.KVIZ20MEDIUM" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.Kviz10Hard"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.KVIZ10HARD" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.Kviz20Hard"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.KVIZ20HARD" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.Kviz20"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.KVIZ20" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.Menu"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.MENU" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.Izbor"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.IZBOR" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.Rezultat"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.REZULTAT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.Prefs"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/PrefsTheme"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.PREFS" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
                     />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


            <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.PogresanOdgovor"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.POGRESANODGOVOR" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


            <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.TacanOdgovor"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.TACANODGOVOR" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.RezultatVreme"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="rs.androidaplikacije.flagsandmoney.REZULTATVREME" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your entire manifest file.

Comment: OK mate, in a moment.

Comment: The google play report and the Manifest you posted do no match for things like the read phone state, and it doesn't seem like you are getting the auto-add of legacy permissions for failure to declare an sdk version.  Perhaps you uploaded a stale apk based on earlier sources; try cleaning the project and re-exporting.  Also install it locally and see what the phone says the permissions are.

Comment: It's the latest version of my app. I will try to install it locally.

Comment: I've tried it locally and it has phone calls permissions.

Answer (score 0):

> public static final String  ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Allows applications to access information about networks
>
> Constant Value:   "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE), this seems to mean ALL networks, including the phone.

Comment: I use that to check if the wifi or 3G is on or off. What's that has to do with phone calls?